# Nginx remove php extension and index from url

Tags: nginx

Hope someone can help me.
be aware; sorry for possible bad english ;)
I'm trying for hours to setup my configs so my site is accessible without php extension, but will redirect any request with extension and in addition remove the /index from URL.

i have come to the point where every extension will removed and still got parsed by php5-fpm.

here is my current code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php;

    <<unrelated Modulecode>>

    rewrite ^(.*).php(.*)$ $1$2 permanent; # << forces index to be appended, so not exactly wanted
    #rewrite ^/index$ / permanent; >> results in infinity loop for indexpage

    # location ~ ^(.*)(?<!(index)).php(.*)$ { # << even don't know how to at least except index...gwarz regex x|
    #     rewrite ^(.*).php(.*)$ $1$2 permanent;
    # }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phprule;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ 404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @phprule {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

the uncommented parts are some desperate trys to get it somehow to work x<

so what i want to accomplish:

example.com/index.php => example.com/

example.com/foo.php => example.com/foo

example.com/some/path/foo.php => example.com/some/path/foo

hope you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Probably found the issue or moved on, but for the benefit of those who come along after, these little changes did the trick for me:

```
location @phprule {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ "/$1.php" last;
}
```

`/` added to the regex, quotes and a forward slash added to the rewrite string.

Comment: Ohh thanks that somebody run also into the same problem and tried to solve it, but how exactly did you now redirected the call to index(.php) itself?