# Remove .php from pages in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

How do i make pages on my website display without .php ? Preferably with example.php being redirected to /example so i dont get penalized for duplicate content by Google.

Everything below has failed for me and ends up generating a `404` error when i view /example or the /example is downloaded instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911610/6016130

https://www.nullis.net/weblog/2011/05/nginx-rewrite-remove-file-extension/

Does anyone have a suggestion?

P.S. I don't want to pass all files to `php-fpm` as that would only decrease security.

Comment: PHP is not a extension of Nginx.

Comment: I dont mean php extension like apache's php extension, i mean the actual ".php" in the address bar.

Comment: You don't want to pass all files to php-fpm because that would decrease security - can you elaborate please? Also, can you try with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851399/nginx-clean-url-with-seo-friendly-file-names) and report back?

Comment: I read some stuff that said passing everything to php-fpm can be used to hack a server box because payload can be included in for instance an uploaded image file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.. what is "everything"? css and js files too? Also, where did you read that stuff? People spout nonsense all the time on internet, don't trust everything someone writes and I'm sure that there was a context with that security part that you omitted now.

Comment: @N.B. I tried that out, but i get 404 errors on php files even when phphandler dir exists. That method won't work for me either as i also want php files to be processed from subdirectories.

Comment: oh oh It's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at [Nginx remove php extension and index from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819897/nginx-remove-php-extension-and-index-from-url)  and it worked for me!

Thanks for everyone's help regardless.